# -Wconversion for short and char

Tags: c

I added `-Wconversion` to my build options.  The first warning is for this function (evidently for reversing endianness):

```
unsigned short reverse(unsigned short val) {
    return (val<<8) | (val>>8);
}
```

I think I see what's happening here.  `val` is getting promoted to `signed int` for purposes of the shift and bitwise `|`.  Then, this needs to be converted back into an `unsigned short`.

However, I don't really have a good solution to this.  The original intent works best if the promotion never happens, but there isn't a suffix for shorts that I'm aware of that would prevent it.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would advice to use types with explicitly specified size. According to the C standard `unsigned short` is a type which is less or equal to `unsigned int` and *at least* 16 bits. So to reverse an unsigned 16 bit wide integer you should use, literally, uint16_t. Also you should drop the upper part when you perform left shift:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint16_t reverse(uint16_t _v) {
    return ((uint16_t)((_v & 0xFF) << 8) | (_v >> 8));
}
```

This file is compiled cleanly with my GCC-4.7.2 with -Wall -Wconversion -Werror. Besides, there're [`htons()` and `ntohs()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons).

Comment: "Also you should drop the upper part when you perform left shift" why is this necessary?

Comment: Well, actually, it's not necessary :-) I have checked the disassembled code of the function (gcc-4.7.2), and it's the same with and without `(_v & 0xFF)` for both '-O2' (and higher) and '-Os' (although the sequences depend on optimization flags, but they don't depend on the presence of `(_v & 0xFF)`. So it's just a matter of taste, for me it looks clearer, but certainly YMMV.